# shellexecute fails to open http links for some users

Tags: delphi, http, browser, shellexecute

Some users of an app of mine are reporting links dont open in the browser. I always launch them with shellexecute(0, 'open', 'http://...

what could I check for an incorrect(?) setting in the http link associations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're assuming that the browser registered the `open` verb. It may not have done so.

Just pass nil as the second parameter and omit the `open`, and let the OS determine what the default action is for the http:// protocol, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like the default browser is not functioning quite right. I guess the first thing I would try is to have them enter an (any) url into start->run and see if that pops up.

You could also have them register what the settings on the URL below are:

http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/solved-fix-default-protocol-http-association-in-windows/

Or use the ftype utility on the cmdline:

```
C:\Users\marco>ftype http
http="C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -nohome
```

These operate on registry keys under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*protocolname* with protocolname=http/ftp etc.

Making a simple app to dump these keys might help finding out what the pattern here is.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this failure can be dynamic -- i.e., the old MS PhotoEditor would block opening URLS using ShellExecute. (C.f., http://code.activestate.com/recipes/334665/ ). Fix is as noted in the recipe: write out an .HTML file and shellexecute that.